# How to Get lists of all installed font families in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Can anyone tell me how I can get lists of all installed fonts in c# uwp? I just want to put those fonts in combo box. So, I just need a list that has all the installed fonts of the PC.

I also tried to use Win2D but it gave me null output. My code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var fonts = Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Text.CanvasTextFormat.GetSystemFontFamilies();
    BaseExample.ItemsSource = fonts;
}
```

Comment: I am using UWP. So, System.Drawing.Text is not available in UWP

Comment: Sorry, none of those helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install the [Win2D](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm) Nuget package.

Then you can call the [CanvasTextFormat.GetSystemFontFamilies](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Text_CanvasTextFormat_GetSystemFontFamilies.htm) method to return a list of the installed fonts.

Comment: I have already tried it but it just gave me null output.

Comment: Well, at this point, you're going to have to add the code you tried to your question.

Comment: The return value for that method is a `string[]`. Is your `fonts` variable actually `null`, or is it a zero-length array?

Comment: When I try this I get this exception:

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

BaseExample was null.

Comment: That means that you're trying to set the `ItemsSource` property on a null reference. That is outside the scope of this question. What about the value of the `fonts` variable? How many entries are in that array?

Comment: I have found that the array is not null the only problem is that `comboFonts.ItemsSource = fonts;` or `comboFonts.Items.Add("TEST");` is not working I can add from xaml but not from c#.

Comment: Well we can't keep going back in forth in comments, and it sounds like your original question has been resolved. If you continue to struggle, you will have to ask a separate question.